# Displaying different values based on another value in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Sorry, I'm not sure how to properly work what I want to achieve, although that's mostly the problem. I'm sure the answer is simple and I lack the grammar...

I have an image tag bound to an object via Angular. The object has two properties - one is "FileName" and contains the name of the image (e.g. myimage.jpg). The other is "FilePath" and it's the problem here. FilePath doesn't contain an actual path, it has a number. So for example:

22 = /images/
43 = /photos/
66 = /thumbnails/

and so on. So in my image tag I want to do something like this:

```
<img src="FilePath + FileName" /> (Yes I know that's not valid syntax)
```

But since FilePath isn't a path, I need some sort of way, such as a switch or an if or a converter/filter type of setup so I can determine the correct path from  the number and then marry it up to the image name.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to convert the number to the correct path and return it.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
   .controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
     $scope.imgPath = '23';
     $scope.imgSrc = 'FileName'
     $scope.getPath = function() {
       switch($scope.imgPath) {
           case '23': return '/images/'
           case '43': return '/photos/'
           case '66': return '/thumbnails/'
       }
     }
   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <img ng-src="{{getPath() + imgSrc}}" />
    <h1>{{getPath() + imgSrc}}</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```